# In rails 5, how do I only have one validation message if I leave a field empty/blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5, is-empty

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this in my model ...

```
  belongs_to :crypto_currency

  validates :crypto_currency, presence: true
```

The issue is when I save my model from a form, two errors come back if I don't set a value for the "Crypto_currency" field ...

```
Crypto currency must exist
Crypto currency Please select a value for crypto currency.
```

This is my config/locales/en.yml file.  I still have to work out how to remove the "Crypto currency" words from the "Crypto currency Please select a value for crypto currency." error message, but you can clearly see I have only defined one error message in the file

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user_notification:
          attributes:
            crypto_currency:
              blank: "Please select a value for crypto currency."
```

How do I only have one error message for my model's field if it is not entered?

**Edit:** In respone to comments, here's how I display ther ror messages

```
  <ul>
  <% @user_notification.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: If you do a breakpoint (`byebug`) and run `user_notification..errors.full_messages` what do you see? What about just `user_notification.errors`?

Comment: How are you showing the errors in your form? Are both errors on the field or one for the form and one for the field?

Comment: Included how I dplsya the error messages as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your model like this:

```
belongs_to :crypto_currency, optional: true
validates :crypto_currency, presence: true
```

And

```
en:  
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user_notification:
        crypto_currency: ""
    errors:
      models:
        user_notification:
          attributes:
            crypto_currency:
              blank: "Please select a value for crypto currency."
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 makes `belongs_to` association required by default

`belongs_to :crypto_currency` adds validation, so you don't need your own.

You can skip `belongs_to` default validation like this:

```
belongs_to :crypto_currency, optional: true
```

Or delete your own and customize the default error message

Comment: It odsen't work.  I removed my own validation, added the "required: true" as you suggested, but the error message that appears is "Crypto currency must exist" as opposed to the custom one I want to appear.

Comment: required: false

Comment: If you remove your own validation, then it should be `belongs_to :crypto_currency, required: true` and `required: "Please select a value for crypto currency."` in the locales. If you want to keep your validation, then do `required: false` and do not change locales

Comment: Right, I removed my own, put "required: true" and got teh single error message""Crypto currency must exist" (not what I had in locales).   If I put "required: false" and include my own custom validation, I get a single error, "Crypto currency Please select a value for crypto currency.", still not quite what I had in the locales (somehow "Crypto currency" is getting pre-pended)

Comment: In the second case this is expected behaviour. Rails adds attribute name to the beginning of the error message. You should consider that

Comment: Try using `blank` instead of 'required' in locales (as it is now in your question) and use default belongs_to validation, not your own

Comment: Although taht's the default behavior, taht's not what I want.  But thanks for giving it a go.

Comment: The problem in the issue was "why 2 messages?". The problem about wrong error message has nothing to do with this one. So, you should mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I beleive that instead of `required: false` it's `optional: true` is the right way to disable this. For people (like me) that updated from and older Rails, don't  have the _new_framework_defaults.rb_ initializer with `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true`